# IllegalArgumentException when I use ActiveMQ in JBoss AS 7

Tags: jboss, activemq-classic

I get the next error after run jboss 7 in standalone.

16:09:35,699 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC00002:    Invocation of listener "org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.ParsedRaDeploymentProcessor$1@20863d22" failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS014809: A node is already registered at '(deployment => activemq-rar-5.7.0.rar)'   at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.ConcreteResourceRegistration.registerSubModel(ConcreteResourceRegistration.java:108) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.AbstractResourceRegistration.registerSubModel(AbstractResourceRegistration.java:68) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]   at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.AbstractResourceRegistration.registerOverrideModel(AbstractResourceRegistration.java:97) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.ParsedRaDeploymentProcessor$1.transition(ParsedRaDeploymentProcessor.java:181) [jboss-as-connector-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.invokeListener(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1416) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.access$2700(ServiceControllerImpl.java:49) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]     at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ListenerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1954) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]

Anybody Can help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in 7.1.1.Final.jar. It's because there are two ironjacamar.xml files in the path. I was able to get this to work using ailed: Jboss AS 7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT